# Make Java set threadsafe

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, android-volley

I'm updating a set inside the Volley's `onResponse` callback like this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response)
{
    if (!response.equals(Properties.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND) || !response.equals(Properties.USER_NOT_FOUND))
    {
        if (user.getFavoriteProducts().contains(product.getId()))
        {
            user.getFavoriteProducts().remove(product.getId());

        } else {
            user.getFavoriteProducts().add(product.getId());
        }

        mSharedPreferencesManager.insertUser(user);
    }
}
```

When two response are received at the same time this set is accesed simultaneously. I'm trying to make this set thread safe, but I can't get it to work, this is what I've tried so far:

**Use a SynchronizedSet:**

```
user.setFavoriteProducts(Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Long>()));
```

**Use a CopyOnWriteArraySet:**

```
user.setFavoriteProducts(new CopyOnWriteArraySet<Long>());
```

**Synchronize the code inside the callback:**

```
private static final Object object = new Object();

@Override
public void onResponse(String response)
{
    synchronized (object)
    {
        if (!response.equals(Properties.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND) || !response.equals(Properties.USER_NOT_FOUND))
        {
            if (user.getFavoriteProducts().contains(product.getId()))
            {
                user.getFavoriteProducts().remove(product.getId());

            } else {
                user.getFavoriteProducts().add(product.getId());
            }

            mSharedPreferencesManager.insertUser(user);
        }
    }
}
```

None of these have worked, any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**: What's not working is that only one item is inserted.

---

**EDIT 2**: I've tried N0un's approach and still only one item is inserted

This is the code I've used:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(final String response)
{
    Log.d(Properties.TAG, "[REST_CLIENT] Response received: " + response);

    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized (RestClient.class)
            {
                if (!response.equals(Properties.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND) || !response.equals(Properties.USER_NOT_FOUND))
                {
                    if (user.getFavoriteProducts().contains(product.getId()))
                    {
                        Log.d(Properties.TAG, "[REST_CLIENT] Removing product from favorites: " + product.getId());
                        user.getFavoriteProducts().remove(product.getId());

                    } else {
                        Log.d(Properties.TAG, "[REST_CLIENT] Adding product to favorites: " + product.getId());
                        user.getFavoriteProducts().add(product.getId());
                    }

                    Log.d(Properties.TAG, "[REST_CLIENT] Updating user");
                    mSharedPreferencesManager.insertUser(user);

                    Log.d(Properties.TAG, "[REST_CLIENT] Set size: " + user.getFavoriteProducts().size());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

These are the logs I'm getting:

```
D/CUOKA: [REST_CLIENT] Response received: ACCEPTED
D/CUOKA: [REST_CLIENT] Adding product to favorites: 3921
D/CUOKA: [REST_CLIENT] Updating user
D/CUOKA: [REST_CLIENT] Response received: ACCEPTED
D/CUOKA: [REST_CLIENT] Set size: 1
D/CUOKA: [REST_CLIENT] Adding product to favorites: 2361
D/CUOKA: [REST_CLIENT] Updating user
D/CUOKA: [REST_CLIENT] Set size: 1
```

---

**EDIT 3**: this is the code to insert the user into the SharedPreferences:

```
public synchronized boolean insertUser(final User user)
{
    mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(user);

    mEditor.putString(KEY_USER, json);

    return mEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: *but I can't get it to work*? What happens?

Comment: Please provide info for what did not work. How did you test and what is the wrong behavior you see.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Sorry, I've edited the question. Only one of the items is inserted into the set.

Comment: What errors you are getting when using SynchronizedSet,CopyOnWriteArraySet and synchronized block?

Comment: Could you provide a log to see how many times you are in `onResponse` please? In this log (which should be the first instruction of the method), you should print the `response`, the `user.getFavoriteProducts()` list, and the current `product.getId()`.

Comment: @PravinD I'm not getting any errors, simply one of the items is not inserted, so favoriteList has only one item.

Comment: @N0un Ok, will do asap

Comment: @cuoka Try to add `onErrorResponse` listener too to see if there is error or not.

Comment: @N0un I have it set too, the onResponse is called twice, I'll post the logs when I can.

Comment: OP, you just need to synchronize on the set itself and not any other object or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Volley's listeners are called in the UI thread using an classic Java `Executor`. I think there is a mechanism that cancel some listener calls when there is too much work in the UI thread.

Try that:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response)
{
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized (MyClassName.class) {
                if (!response.equals(Properties.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND)
                        || !response.equals(Properties.USER_NOT_FOUND)) {
                    if (user.getFavoriteProducts().contains(product.getId())) {
                        user.getFavoriteProducts().remove(product.getId());

                    } else {
                        user.getFavoriteProducts().add(product.getId());
                    }

                    mSharedPreferencesManager.insertUser(user);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

See these responses too: [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529689/6523232) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639633/6523232) for more explanation.

> Simply move that data processing that is performed inside your listeners to a background thread / AsyncTask to free your UI thread and prevent the blocking.

**EDIT:** After some discussion and code review, I found the (second) problem: `user` is retrieved before the request and the thread-safety problem was here. The `user`'s data was not yet saved while a new request was in progress. So the second request works on the same `Set` than the first one, and not in the new updated `Set`. So `user` should be retrieved in the `synchronized` block I suggested, before other treatments.

Comment: Will give it a try as soon as I can!

Comment: I'm trying to undestand this. So, the responses are processed in the UI Thread, but, what happens when two responses are received at the same time?

Comment: @cuoka When you use your `synchronized` it is thread safe. That mean only one thread can handle the instruction block at the time, so no problem in your example with `synchronized`. But without it, if two threads are executing your code at the same time, one of them can modify the list (`add` for example) while the other is reading (`contains`) and that may produce unexpected behaviors like data corruption or missing some processes. But why your code doesn't work on the UI thread, I don't really know. I suppose that there is some kind of blocking and some task are cancelled for prevent UI lag.

Comment: If this code is run in the UI Thread, that means that there's no parallelism, right? I don't quite understand why I need to make this code thread-safe. Although I understand why I should execute that code in a seperate thread.

Comment: @cuoka For the sample of code you provided, it is not necessary to make it thread safe, right! (Except if you do some treatments to your lists on another thread at the same time,...). But now, you know you probably have to process your answer on background thread (`AsyncTask` for example) and turn your `onResponse` it thread safe is mandatory for that (if you use separated threads)

Comment: I've tried your code and still the same happens :( I've updated my question with the code and the logs.

Comment: @cuoka It sounds like your `user` object is not the same for the first and the second `onResponse` call... Does `mSharedPreferencesManager.insertUser(user);` make a copy? Try to show in log the following `System.identityHashCode(user);` please (you could show the same for your list (`System.identityHashCode(user.getFavoriteProducts());`) if the code for `user` is the same the two times.

Comment: Furthermore, what kind of `set` are you using? (`user.getFavoriteProducts()`)

Comment: I've updated the question with the code to insert the user. I don't think I'm creating any copy. I will post the logs when I can. Regarding the type of set, I'm using a HashSet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131136/discussion-between-n0un-and-cuoka).

Answer (score -1):

Listeners are using `Main Thread` (UI thread) so probably some kind of blocking is happening. You should move your data processing to the background thread or make processing async.

Regarding Set sync, you should use `ConcurentHashMap` and simply wrap Set around using `newSetFromMap()` method from Collections.